# Sqlite_Content Provider assistant

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

I am trying to get my ListView to refresh by using a Content Provider. I have created my Provider and have tried to link it propelry to my SqlLite DB. Once I have my provider completed I will implement my cursorloader but 1st I need help with my provider. I have not found and detailed information for novice users on how to create a content provider. any assistance would be appreciated. My DB and Provider are posted below.  My main issue is trying to create a URI that links to my DB.

DB:

```
 public class dataStore extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//Table attributes
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SiteLogindb";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
public static final String TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE = "infoTable";

// Data attributes
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SITE = "sName";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS = "wUrl";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME = "uName";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD = "pWord";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NOTES = "lNotes";



public dataStore(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String sqlDataStore = "create table if not exists " +
        TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE + " ("+ BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"

                    + COLUMN_NAME_SITE + " text not null,"
                    + COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS + " text not null,"
                    + COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME + " text not null,"
                    + COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD + " text not null,"
                    + COLUMN_NAME_NOTES + " text not null);";

        db.execSQL(sqlDataStore);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(oldVersion == 1 && newVersion == 2){
            //Upgrade the database

     }

        }
          }
```

Content Provider:

```
           public class ListProvider extends ContentProvider {
private dataStore lDB;

private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.loginplus.home.ListProvider";
public static final int TUTORIALS = 1;
public static final int TUTORIAL_ID = 2;
private static final String TUTORIALS_BASE_PATH = "tutorials";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
        + "/" + TUTORIALS_BASE_PATH);
public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE
        + "/mt-tutorial";
public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE
        + "/mt-tutorial";

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    lDB = new dataStore(getContext());
    return true;
}

private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(
        UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
static {
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TUTORIALS_BASE_PATH, TUTORIALS);
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TUTORIALS_BASE_PATH + "/#", TUTORIAL_ID);
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(dataStore.TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE);
    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (uriType) {
    case TUTORIAL_ID:
        queryBuilder.appendWhere(dataStore.DATABASE_VERSION + "="
                + uri.getLastPathSegment());
        break;
    case TUTORIALS:
        // no filter
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI");
    }
    Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(lDB.getReadableDatabase(),
            projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return cursor;
}
//Deleting DB entries
@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = lDB.getWritableDatabase();
    int rowsAffected = 0;
    switch (uriType) {
    case TUTORIALS:
        rowsAffected = sqlDB.delete(dataStore.TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE,
                selection, selectionArgs);
        break;
    case TUTORIAL_ID:
        String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
            rowsAffected = sqlDB.delete(dataStore.TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE,
                    BaseColums.ID + "=" + id, null);
        } else {
            rowsAffected = sqlDB.delete(dataStore.TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE,
                    selection + " and " + BaseColums.ID + "=" + id,
                    selectionArgs);
        }
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown or Invalid URI " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return rowsAffected;
}
@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
//Inserting DB entries
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
}
//updating DB entries
@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs) {
    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = lDB.getWritableDatabase();
    int rowsAffected = 0;
    switch (uriType) {
    case TUTORIALS:
        rowsAffected = sqlDB.update(dataStore.TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE,
                null, selection, selectionArgs);
        break;
    case TUTORIAL_ID:
        String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
            rowsAffected = sqlDB.update(dataStore.TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE,
                    null, BaseColums.ID + "=" + id, null);
        } else {
            rowsAffected = sqlDB.update(dataStore.TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE,
                    null, selection + " and " + BaseColums.ID + "=" + id,
                    selectionArgs);
        }
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown or Invalid URI " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return rowsAffected;
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My main issue is trying to create a URI that links to my DB.

- Right now your `ListProvider.CONTENT_URI` will match in your `ListProvider` using your `UriMatcher`. And your `ListProvider` is using your `dataStore.TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE` which is the only table in your database.
- So you can already use your `ContentProvider` directly by using a `ContentResolver` in your `Activity` with code like this:

  ```
   getContentResolver().query(ListProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
   getContentResolver().delete(ListProvider.CONTENT_URI, where, selectionArgs);
   //etc...
  ```

---

> Once I have my provider completed I will implement my cursorloader but 1st I need help with my provider.

- Your `ContentProvider` appears to be done. However, you must remember to add it to your manifest with the same `AUTHORITY`. You can rename the authority, but it must be unique and match in your `ContentProvider and your manifest.

  ```
  <provider
      android:name="com.loginplus.home.ListProvider"
      android:authorities="com.loginplus.home.ListProvider" >
  </provider>
  ```
- You will then be able to create your `CursorLoader` in the `public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args)` callback.

  ```
  CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, ListProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, orderBy);
  ```

---

> I have not found and detailed information for novice users on how to create a content provider. any assistance would be appreciated.

- Lars Vogella has a great [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) that walks you through creating your own `SQLite database`, `ContentProvider`, and `CursorLoader`. This helped me get started and gave me a great basis.